# Qt C++ QCompleter Custom Popup

Tags: c++, qt, qcombobox, qcompleter

Could I change the QCompleter popup to show custom widgets instead of stringlists?

I wanted to show three parameters of an object in one Item.

Something like this (Image shows a grid, a list would be good enough).

[image]

Implementing a QAbstractItemView as @eyllanesc suggested must be a way out. but i don't understand how is it done.

Any sample code would be helpful.

Other solutions :

1. Can I add a tooltip for each suggestion?
2. Would it be easier to create a custom QLineEdit with a layout with required widgets loaded underneath it and filter the layout on key press event to look like a QCompletor.

Comment: Show us your code and what you have tried please.

Comment: @eyllanesc, I have not found a way to change the popup view. All i have is simple completer with a stringlist loaded to it

Comment: The QCompleter class has a method  [setPopup](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcompleter.html#setPopup)

Comment: I think you could start by creating a class that inherits from QAbstractItemView, and give it the style you want, and then pass an object of that class to QCompleter using the above method.

Comment: I recommend you implement a QTableView since it inherits from QAbstractItemView, you could easily handle it with QStyledItemDelegate.